# My SE Uploader has stopped working

Tags: support

The SE Uploader which has always worked well has stopped working. I reinstalled it and I get the pallette. However, when I click on Image the Wolfram window pops up with

```
SETools`SEUploader`Private`stackImage::parseErr: Could not parse the answer of the server.
```

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/issues) might be a good spot to reach halirutan on this matter, or ask him in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)

Answer (score 10):

> The SE Uploader which has always worked well has stopped working. I reinstalled it and I get the palette.

Well, this reminds me of

> An electrical engineer, a mechanical engineer and a software engineer from Microsoft are riding in a car, when they start down a steep hill. Halfway down the brakes go out and the car crashes into a tree at the bottom of the hill. Luckily, no one is hurt, so they get out and start analyzing what happened.
>
> Electrical engineer: Clearly a short-circuit in the ABS system caused the brakes to go out.
>
> Mechanical engineer: No, no, it was an over-pressure situation that caused a brake line to rupture.
>   They both turn to the Microsoft guy and ask him for his opinion:
>
> Microsoft guy: I don't know, but let's push the car back to the top of the hill and try it again.

I fixed the issue. If you click on `Update` you should see a new version 130 or you can use

```
Import["http://goo.gl/rQtfHZ"]
```

to reinstall the palette.

Btw, it was not a bug of mine. I have stopped writing bugs a long time ago. It was an issue introduced by stackexchange's switch to `https` for image hosting.

Comment: I could not click on Update and make it work due to the difficulties of deleting the directory. So I now have a working version based on your Import expression. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hugh Good. The updater is a hack because I need to overwrite the original directory which does not work in all circumstance and all operating systems.  If everything fails, you can go to `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` and delete the `SETools` manually next time.

Comment: I found it a lot of days ago, but I though it is just a case-by-case on me **again**.So I have not bothered you.And as my try, the version *130* is work well.Thanks fro fix. :)

Comment: I would very much like to know how you achieved the 'not write bugs anymore' bit? :-) Somehow I seem to still be stick in that mode.

Comment: I am afraid the uploader has stopped working again. I tried to Import again but its still not working... any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I'll give the same answer as last time, just to be proven wrong later :) For me [it still works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AkaDx.png).